# How to Prevent Linke break for Divs in CSS?

Tags: php, html, css, layout

I am creating menu for a website. for each item (Home, Contact us, About us) I use Background color and text of size 125X30. In CSS, When i use float it works correct. But when i removed float, all individual item such as home, contact etc come down one by one. I need it left to right in a single line without float. Help me

Comment: Why you can't use `float`. What you try to achieve is exactly what the `float` if for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rajasekar,

Stu Nicholls of CSSplay has the following horizontal menu without using floats:

**CSS**

```
.menu {display:inline-block;}
.menu {display:inline;}
.holder {display:table;}

.menu {
  display:table-row;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  list-style-type:none;
  white-space:nowrap; 
  }
.menu li {display:inline;}
.menu a, .menu a:visited {
  display:block;
  float:left;
  padding:4px 16px;
  color:#000; 
  background:#d4d4d4; 
  border:1px solid #fff; 
  text-decoration:none;
  }
.menu a:hover {
  color:#fff; 
  background:#08c;
  }

#wrapper1 {text-align:left;}
#wrapper1 .holder {margin:0;
```

**html**

```
<div id="wrapper1">
<div class="holder">
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="#nogo">Tab One</a></li>
<li><a href="#nogo">Tab Two: Longer</a></li>
<li><a href="#nogo">Tab Three: Longest</a></li>
<li><a href="#nogo">Tab Four</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Further explanation (including the use of display:inline-block) [is on CSSplay](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/centered2.html).

Comment: You are using floats! .menu a { flat: left; } But I would agree on using floats. The layout makes perfect sense and use for floats.

Answer (score 3):

If float is working, I'd recommend sticking with that - you might just need a clearing element afterwards, since this is a common source of problems.

If you really can't go with floats, you could use `display: inline-block`

Answer (score 1):

Your items are probably inside a block level element (ex: div, li, p).

In short: Block elements, below the last one. Inline, next to the last one.

You need to make your items as inline. Simply replace the block level tags with inlines (ex: span) or style them with `display: inline` or `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

You have some possibilities, but i think float is the best way.

1. You could set the div's to display:inline-block (but i wouldn't recommend that)

   - Also you could do absolute positioning, but this is also no neat solution.